# ¿Cómo mostrar datos de un JSON guardados en un arreglo?

Tags: vue.js

necesito guardar y mostrar los datos de un json... Puedo guardar el json en mi arreglo pero al momento de leer los datos no me deja.

Mi código:

Esta es una función que recibe como parámetro "champion" el cual es un nombre, por ejemplo: **"Aatrox"**. Luego asigno la respuesta a la data **this.champion_info** y la muestro por consola.

```
get_data_selected(champion) {
      axios
        .get(
          `http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.25.1/data/es_MX/champion/${champion}.json`
        )
        .then(response => {
          this.champion_info = response.data.data.champion; <--- Necesito el nombre del campeón
          console.log(this.champion_info); <--- Me devuelve undefined
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error.message);
        });
}
```

Entonces, cómo puedo hacer que entre a ese nombre porque sin el **"champion"** en la respuesta queda de la siguiente manera:

```
{__ob__: Observer}
Aatrox: Object
allytips: (...)
blurb: (...)
enemytips: (...)
id: (...)
image: (...)
info: (...)
key: (...)
lore: (...)
name: (...)
partype: (...)
passive: (...)
recommended: (...)
skins: (...)
spells: (...)
stats: (...)
tags: (...)
title: (...)
```

Y no puedo mostrar los datos, por ejemplo el dato **this.champion_info.name**.

Comment: que tiene response data? no sobra un data?

Comment: {__ob__: Observer}
data: (...)
format: (...)
type: (...)
version: (...)
__ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
get data: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set data: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get format: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set format: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get type: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set type: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get version: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set version: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
__proto__: Object

Comment: Me devuelve eso, por eso pongo otro data, para que ingrese a los datos del json

Comment: dentro de data hay otro data? no entiendo eso que mostras... deberia haber un solo data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es llamarlo como índice de un arreglo

```
this.champion_info = response.data.data[champion];
```

Así la podrías acceder usando lo que tiene la variable `champio`.

Asi tu codigo quedaria de la siguiente manera

```
get_data_selected(champion) {
      axios
        .get(
          `http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.25.1/data/es_MX/champion/${champion}.json`
        )
        .then(response => {
          this.champion_info = response.data.data[champion];
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.message);
    });
}
```

Comment: Si me funcionó, Gracias!

Comment: @AlanOrtega ¿Esta respuesta solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!